# Kernel Panic on the default kernel

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, kernel, btrfs

I have kernel panic on my default kernel (v.4.15.108) and it boots to `initramfs` only. If I change to the previous kernel (v.4.15.101), I am able to successfully boot my machine and everything is working correctly. I got that by trying to revert to a previous `btrfs` snapshot. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with `btrfs` filesystem.

I have executed the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.15.0-108-generic
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.15.0-108-generic
sudo apt autoremove -y 
sudo update-initramfs -u -k 4.15.0-101-generic
sudo update-grub
```

but when I reboot my system, it still tries to boot to the default kernel and I am stuck at `initramfs`. I guess fixing this should be very easy and straight-forward but I really don't know how to force the default grub to ignore kernel v.4.15.108. It is strange that even if I execute `sudo apt upgrade` it doesn't find the new kernel. I thought that re-installing the kernel my fix my issue, but after I have installed the new kernel v.4.15.108, image, image-generic and headers, when I restart I don't even get to `initramfs`, I have just a blinking underscore on a black screen.

Comment: Have you tried any of the v5 series kernels?

Comment: no, I have not.

Comment: v4.15.109 is out now; maybe that one will work better.